# Rapidly clicking a navigation bar button, results in a view getting pushed multiple times

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem, uistoryboardsegue

I am using 3 view controllers A, B, C. 
Added a push segue in storyboard from A to B (say segue1) and B to C (say segue2).
A is embedded in a navigation controller.

In A, I am adding a right bar button and performing segue1 on its action.
Similarly in B, I am adding another right bar button and performing segue2 on its action.

If I click the button rapidly multiple times, view B gets pushed once and then view C gets pushed multiple times on it.

Is this a known issue? or Is there something wrong in my implementation?

Edit: Adding code

**ViewController A:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(insertB:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
}

- (void)insertB:(id)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue1" sender:sender];
}
```

**ViewController B:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(insertC:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
}

- (void)insertC:(id)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue2" sender:sender];
}
```

Comment: Show some code to see if there is something wrong with your implementation

Answer (score 0):

Set the `userInteractionEnabled` property of the button to `false` when pressed, and after pushing change it to `true`.

Comment: Is this always required in such type of implementation?

Comment: No. But it could be that the app is making a request which takes time before proceeding to the next view, this allows the button to be pressed multiple times before the progress is over. Can you show some code?

Comment: No app is not making any request, I tested in on a very simple project with no other code. Please check the added code in question